# getting data from db to list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model

I have data in table which has no Primary Key in SQL. In Entity Framework model I set PK to acol (even though there are multiple rows for some values of acol).

data is store as follows

```
AAATable
    acol bcol 
    124   125 
    124   126
```

I have such query

```
        var AAATableList = (from tdrc in db.AAATable
                                      where tdrc.acol == id
                                      select tdrc).ToList();
```

Then I make a loop to log the data

```
        foreach (var itemB in AAATableList)
        {
            Logger.WriteLog("AAATable.txt", itemB.bcol.ToString());               
        }
```

Of crouse, there are 2 rows in the table so 2 rows I wrote in the log, but the value is written as follows

125

125

Instead of 125,126

**UPDATE**

`AAATable.Count()`  returns 2

`AAATable.First().bcol.ToString()` returns 125

`AAATable.First().acol.ToString()` returns 124

`AAATable.Last().bcol.ToString()` returns 125

`AAATable.Last().acol.ToString()` returns 124

The Idea is to get 125 and 126 value while looping that foreach loop,
But instead of that, I'm getting 125 and 125

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and in Entity Framework model I set PK to acol. so maybe that is the
>   answer ?

Yes, that is the cause of the issue. You told Entity Framework that `acol` was a PK, but your data looks like:

```
AAATable
    acol bcol 
    124   125 
    124   126
```

In other words, you lied to Entity Framework (you said there was only one record per value of 124) and it [caught you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_map_pattern) in the lie. :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works,

just making sure you put two primary keys to  `acol` and `bcol` in the EF Model

[image]